# Equivalent definitions of connectedness

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am trying to show that if, for a subset $A$ of a topological space $X$, there exists a pair $J,K$ of open subsets of $X$ s.t. $A\subset J\cup K$, $J\cap K \cap A=\emptyset$, $A\not\subset J$ and $A\not \subset K$, then $A$ is not connected (i.e. there exist open, disjoint, nonempty $U,V \subset X$ s.t. $A=U\cup V$).

So I suppose there exist such $J,K$.  Then $A\cap J \neq \emptyset$ and $A\cap K \neq \emptyset$.  But $A=A\cap(J\cup K)=(A\cap J)\cup (A\cap K
)$ and obviously $A\cap J$ and $A\cap K$ are disjoint and nonempty.  Then we can let $U=A\cap J$ and $V=A\cap K$ in the usual definition of disconnectedness given above.

But I do not understand how we necessarily have both $A\cap J$ and $A\cap K$ open, regardless of whether $A$ is closed, open, clopen, or neither closed nor opwn.

Comment: Your proof does not fail. Are you familiar with the definition of relative topology? $A \cap J$ is open in A if J is open in X.

Comment: I thought that if $A$ is closed, then $A\cap J$ is closed even if $J$ is open in $X$.

Comment: Oh...Is $A$ necessarily open?  Maybe this is where I was confused?

Comment: No, $A$ is not necessarily open. If J and K are open set in $X$, then $A \cap J$ and $A \cap K$ open in $A$

Comment: How can I see that $A\cap J$, say, is always open, regardless of whether $A$ is open, closed, clopen, or neither open nor closed?

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement that $A\cap J$ and $A\cap K$ is open in $X$. Take for example the set $A=\{-1,1\}$ in the standard topology of $\mathbb R$. It should obviously not be connected, but $A\cap J$ and $A\cap K$ must be single points which are closed and not open.

Actually if $A$ is open it's "components" $A\cap J$ and $A\cap K$ must be open and if $A$ is closed the "components" must be closed as well.