# Closed topologist's sine curve is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, solution-verification, connectedness

I have been given a proof that the closed topologist's sine curve $\{{(t,\text{sin}(1/t)):t\neq 0\}}\cup \{{(0,t):-1\leq t \leq t\}}$ is connected.
First, we assume it is not connected.  Let $I=\{{(0,t):-1\leq t \leq t\}}$ and $G=\{{(t,\text{sin}(1/t)):t\neq 0\}}$.  Then there are disjoint, nonempty, open $U,V$ s.t. $I\cup G=U\cup V$.  Then $I=(I\cap U) \cup (I\cap V)$, but $I\cap U$ and $I\cap V$ are open and $I$ is closed, so we have a contradiction.

I do not know how to see that $I\cap U$ and $I \cap V$ are open.  I thought it is possible that they are closed?  I think this issue is analogous to the unanswered question I have here: ([Equivalent definitions of connectedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540693/equivalent-definitions-of-connectedness)).

Answer (score 2):

An easier way is to use that the closure of any connected set is again connected. The topologist's sine curve is the closure of the graph $\{(t, \sin(1/t)) \mid t > 0  \}$, which is path-connected (hence connected).

---

By the above argument, both $$\{ (t, \sin(1/t)) \mid t>0 \} \cup \{(0,t) \mid -1 \leq t \leq 1\}$$ and $$\{ (t, \sin(1/t)) \mid t<0 \} \cup \{(0,t) \mid -1 \leq t \leq 1\}$$are connected. Your topologist's sine curve is the union of these two connected sets, which intersection $\{ (0,t) \mid -1 \leq t \leq 1 \}$ is again connected.

Comment: But I am also considering $t<0$.  Doesn't this complicate using the closure argument?  I would like to understand the proof that I was given, unless I have recorded it incorrectly.  If I have written it incorrectly, I would like to know how to fix it.

Comment: The closure argument is easily fixable, I'll add an edit.

Comment: As for your work, $I \cap U$ and $I \cap V$ being open while $I$ is closed doesn't seem to give a contradiction. These intersections are open in $I$, and $I$ is closed in $I$. But $I$ is connected.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the closure argument!  I could not see it despite looking at this for days!  Still not sure I understand why $I\cap V$ is open, yet.

Comment: I don't think $I \cap V$ is necessarily open in $G$...